# Stacked column and Line in one single chart in Power BI Paginated Report

Tags: linechart, column-chart, powerbi-paginated-reports

Let's suppose this is our dataset:

[image]

We need a stacked column with a line representing the aggregation of the values for each column. With only the areas we manage to generate it:

[image]

However when we add the values column in the series group section we are getting a line for each level present in the chart:

[image]

Is it possible to generate this type of charts ? How can we indicate that the line should be present in each column making reference to the total by area?